# C# Winforms. Ошибка Out of memory при сохранение большего количества картинок через Save()

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, outofmemoryerror

Написал программу, суть которой заключается в том, чтобы нарезать импортированное изображение на множество картинок, после чего экспортировать все эти картинки.

```
int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int bmpSizeW = w / inputW;
        int bmpSizeH = h / inputH;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < picturesCut)
        {
            i++;
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(bmpSizeW * c, bmpSizeH * d, bmpSizeW, bmpSizeH);
            var pic = clearBitmap;
            Bitmap newBitmap = pic.Clone(rectangle, PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555);
            newBitmap.Save(@$"D:\Files\Game Data\Durak\cardsAuto\card{i}.png");
            c++;
            int sizeW = bmpSizeW * c;
            if (sizeW > w)
            {
                c = 0;
                d++;
            }
            labelProgress.Text = $"Progress: {i}/{picturesCut}";
        }
```

После 12 картинки программа завершала работу перенося меня в visual studio и указывая на ошибку Out of memory. Пробовал делать задержку, но на исход это не повлияло, и дело как я понял в мусоре. Почитал документацию по работе с мусором, но для меня это оказалось сложновато. Хотелось бы еще реализовать нормальный вывод прогресса в label, буду рад если с этим тоже поможете.

Comment: _Зевая_ `newBitmap.Dispose();`, а лучше `using Bitmap newBitmap = ...`

Comment: Документация: [Cleaning up unmanaged resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged), [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using). PS: язык переключается в левом нижнем углу.

Comment: Dispose() не помог

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться профилировщиком, хотя в любом случае добавив `newBitmap.Dispose()` вы уже должны были почувствовать разницу

Comment: Нужно больше информации.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема в том что вы "залезаете" за пределы битмапа из которого копируете в тех случаях когдаinputW не кратен w. Это поведение описано в документации (секция исключения) https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.clone?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0